# Get the upload progress

Tags: java, android

My upload method as below:

```
private void upload(String Server, String FilePath, String SavePath, String NewName) {
String end = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary = "*****";
try {
URL url = new URL(ActionUrl);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setUseCaches(false);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/*");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
ds = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + end);
ds.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;" + "name=\"folder\"" + end + end);
ds.write(SavePath.getBytes("UTF-8"));
ds.writeBytes(end);
ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + end);
ds.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;" + "name=\"Filedata\"; filename=\"");
ds.write(NewName.getBytes("UTF-8"));
ds.writeBytes("\"" + end);
ds.writeBytes(end);

FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
int bufferSize = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int length = -1;
while((length = fStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
ds.write(buffer, 0, length);
}       
ds.writeBytes(end);
ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + end);

fStream.close();
ds.flush();
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
int ch;
StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
while((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
b.append((char)ch);
}
System.out.println("UPLOAD" + "SUCCESS");
ds.close();
}
catch(Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I found the line `InputStream is = con.getInputStream();` spend most time.
But how to get the progress of it send?
Or how to modify my method to upload file "by parts"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following code,

First display a Progress Dialog Before calling your upload method,

```
progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(loginAct,"Process ", "please wait....",true,true);

new Thread ( new Runnable()
{
     public void run()
     {
      // your uploading code goes here
     }
}).start();

 Handler progressHandler = new Handler() 
 {

     public void handleMessage(Message msg1) 
     {

         progDailog.dismiss();
         }
 }
```

Comment: I means I do not know how to get the byte which had be send.

Comment: Yes. But I does not know how to get the progress.

Comment: // your uploading code goes here , you need to write your method code in run method.

Comment: no, not that way, just put your whole method's call in run method.

Comment: sure, Please check this link http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/progressBarExample.html

Comment: I know set style STYLE_HORIZONTAL. But I don't know what progress number to set.

Comment: have you check that example running ?

Comment: The method setProgress(int value) how to set?

Comment: just open that link and in the end of page, there is example 1%..2%.. 100%.. as you want,

Comment: L know. But there is a method setProgress(int value) to set the progress. But the value I do not know how to get.

Comment: I mean how to get the number. Not how to show the number format progressbar.